# How to distinguish between pagination and search with spring form tag (Spring MVC)

Tags: forms, spring, search, pagination, tags

```
* SearchVo
public class SearchVo {
    private int startRow;
    private int rowBlockCount = 20;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}


* Controller    
@Controller
public class EmpController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list.do")
    public String list(
        @RequestParam(value = "pageNum", defaultValue = "1") int pageNum, 
        @ModelAttribute("search") SearchVo search, 
        ModelMap modelMap
    ) 
    {
        Map<String, Object> map = empService.list(pageNum, search);

        modelMap.addAttribute("search", search);
        modelMap.addAttribute("list", map.get("list"));
        modelMap.addAttribute("pageUtil", map.get("pageUtil"));

        return "list";
    }
}


* jsp
<form:form modelAttribute="search" action="list.do">
    <form:input path="firstName" />
    <form:input path="secondName" />
    <a  href="javascript:search();">search</a>

    LIST............................

    <div class="pageNavi">
        <span>
            <strong title="current page">1</strong>
            <a href="javascript:act.move('2');">2</a>
            <a href="javascript:act.move('3');">3</a>
            <a href="javascript:act.move('4');">4</a>
            <a href="javascript:act.move('5');">5</a>
        </span>
    </div>

</form:form>
```

It works fine.

I have a question.
After I type "michael" to firstName input box, 
If search button is clicked, it works to search "mechael".

But 
After I type "michael" to firstName input box, 
If page moving button is clicked, It works not only moving page but also searching "mechael" .
I want only page move.

With Spring Form Tag, How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a private field to run checks against like below

```
@Controller
public class EmpController 
{
    private String searchCheck;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list.do")
    public String list(@RequestParam(value = "pageNum", defaultValue = "1") intpageNum, @ModelAttribute("search") SearchVo search, ModelMap modelMap) 
    {
        if (searchCheck.equals(search)
        {
             //search term the same must be move page
        }
        else
        {
              //new search word
              searchCheck = search;
        }

        return "list";
    }
}
```